# I want to convert SwiftUI View (Which is invisible, I mean not rendering the view) to Image/PDF

Tags: objective-c, swift, pdf, url, swiftui

```
let homeVw = HomeView() 
let viewCon = UIHostingController(rootView: homeVw)
let path = viewCon.view!.exportAsPdfFromView() 
print("URL Path \(path)")
```

Here I am Creating HomeView() in swiftUI and With the help of UIHostingViewController getting ViewController With the help of ViewController View I am Trying to generate PDF/ Image. But it is not working. 
Note:- I am not rendering/displaying the HomeView()

Comment: can you please post the code for the issue mentioned?

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/4023941-creating-a-pdf-in-swift-with-pdfkit you can use this tutorial.

Comment: I want to convert View (swiftUI View) to PDF